# WINAPI URLDownloadToFileA Problems

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, declaration

I have used the Microsoft WINAPI syntax from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx).

So, here is my code

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

    HRESULT URLDownloadToFileW(
    FALSE,
    "http://www.dropbox.com/static/images/psychobox.png",
    "C:\\psych0bOx.png",
    0,
    NULL);
```

When i try to compile it with VS12.0 I get these errors:

```
C:\\>cl C:\URLDownloadToFileA.cpp

C:\URLDownloadToFileA.cpp(8) : error C2365: 'URLDownloadToFileA' : redéfinition ; la précédente définition était 'fonction'
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\urlmon.h(4780) : voir la déclaration de 'URLDownloadToFileA'
C:\URLDownloadToFileA.cpp(8) : error C2078: initialiseurs trop nombreux

C:\\>
```

I don't understand why I get these errors.
I'm completely blocked here.

Comment: FYI, especially when posting errors it's much more helpful if they are in English.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFileW(
    FALSE,
    L"http://www.dropbox.com/static/images/psychobox.png",
    L"C:\\psych0bOx.png",
    0,
    NULL);
```

Note that `hr` is a variable of type `HRESULT`.  When `URLDownloadToFileW` function returns `hr` gets assigned some sort of status value you can check.  Probably you can find out if the function downloaded correctly.

Without the `hr` the compiler thinks you are redefining `URLDownloadToFileW`, hence the compiler error.

Note also that the `W` on the end indicates a Unicode function so you need to build your project as Unicode. And because it is a Unicode function you must pass in Unicode string - that is why they are preppended with `L` - means Unicode.

Alternatively use `URLDownloadToFileA` or `URLDownloadToFile` and do not define Unicode.

I just looked up the function (which you could have done) and you will need to do a lot more to make any use of this function.  First thing is to provide the last argument.

Comment: Well if you have changed your code then thats a different problem and a different question.

Comment: You have so much basic stuff to learn,  Get a good book on your language of choice, C or C++, and read.  As a quick tip, your program needs a main function.